# selecting records matching condition A and at least X matching B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table of data as follows

```
|table_id|ref_table_id|is_used|      date         |url|
|--------+------------+-------+-------------------+---|
|1       |1           |       |                   |abc|
|2       |1           |       |2016-01-01 00:00:00|abc|
|3       |1           |0      |                   |abc|
|4       |1           |1      |                   |abc|
|5       |2           |       |                   |   |
|6       |2           |       |2016-01-01 00:00:00|abc|
|7       |2           |1      |                   |abc|
|8       |2           |1      |2016-01-01 00:00:00|abc|
|9       |2           |1      |2016-01-01 00:00:00|abc|
|10      |3           |       |                   |   |
|11      |3           |       |2016-01-01 00:00:00|abc|
|12      |3           |0      |                   |   |
|13      |3           |0      |                   |   |
|14      |3           |0      |2016-01-01 00:00:00|   |
|15      |3           |1      |2016-01-01 00:00:00|abc|
...
|int     |int         |boolean|timestamp          |varchar|
```

As it is obvious, the combination of null values and filled values in the columns `is_used, date, url` has no rules.

Now I want to get distinct `ref_table_id` with conditions

- there is at least 1 row that is **not used** and has **empty `date and url`**
- there are fewer than X rows that are **not used** and **has filled** either
  `date or url`

The table has many rows (~7mil) and groupped ref_table_id can range from 50 rows to 600k rows.

I tried to create this select, which runs for more than 2secs.

```
select 
    distinct on (ref_table_id) t1.ref_table_id, 
    count(1) as my_count
from my_table t1 inner join (
        select distinct t2.ref_table_id from my_table t2
        where t2.is_used is not true -- null or false
            and t2.url is null 
            and t2.date is null 
        group by t2.ref_table_id
    ) tjoin on t1.ref_table_id = tjoin.ref_table_id
where t1.is_used is not true
    and (t1.date is not null
        or t1.url is not null)

group by t1.ref_table_id
having my_count < X
order by 1,2;
```

Can I rewrite it using `INTERSECT`, `VIEW` or other db features so that it would be faster?

Comment: You can remove the GROUP BY from the sub-query. (Keep DISTINCT.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select ref_table_id
from my_table t
group by ref_table_id
having sum(case when is_used = 0 and date is null and url is null
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when is_used = 0 and (date is not null or url is not null)
                then 1 else 0 end) >= N;
```

This checks explicitly for `is_used` to be `0` as the meaning of "not used".  I'm not sure what the blanks represent, so the logic may need to be tweaked.

As a note, you can simplify the query by removing the common condition on `is_used`:

```
select ref_table_id
from my_table t
where is_used = 0  -- or is_used is NULL ??
group by ref_table_id
having sum(case when date is null and url is null
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when (date is not null or url is not null)
                then 1 else 0 end) >= N;
```

Comment: thanks, it is much more readable! I modified a bit the having clause to `.. sum() **and** sum() ` and it is a little faster than original.